# Trying to find out a record that does not exists in a data extension by query

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, dataextensions, automationstudio, sql

So, I total 4 data extensions.

I have records in 3 data extension and I want to save result in data extension# 4.

Here is a sample of how my data extensions looks like:

[image]

Desired result: CustID is the key that exists in all data extension (just by a slightly different column name). I need to find out, ALL records from DataExtension_1 that exists in DataExtension_2 with CustType = 'Student' and Status = 'TRUE' but who do not exists in DataExtension_3 with TravelDate as 13 months or less.

According to this requirement, ID# 3 record should be in the results.

**This is what I have created so far:**

```sql
SELECT a.CustID, a.CustEmail, b.CustType, b.Status FROM DataExtension_1 AS a 
INNER JOIN DataExtension_2  AS b
    ON a.CustID = b.Cust-ID
WHERE b.CustType = 'Student' AND b.Status='true'
INNER JOIN DataExtension_3 AS c
    ON a.CustID = c.Cust--ID
WHERE c.Cust--ID IS NULL AND c.TravelDate < DATEADD(month, -13, GETDATE()
```

**I am getting the following error:**

> The query syntax is invalid
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INNER'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only have one WHERE-clause in your SQL statement, as they are per query rather than per join like in your statement.

So I suggest trying this query (from clarifications in comments and in chat this also includes all the changes necessary to fulfill the asker's requirements):

```sql
SELECT a.CustID, a.CustEmail, b.CustType, b.Status
FROM DataExtension_1 AS a 
INNER JOIN DataExtension_2  AS b
    ON a.CustID = b.Cust-ID
WHERE
    b.CustType = 'Student' AND
    b.Status='true' AND
    a.CustID IN
    (
        SELECT Cust--ID
        FROM DataExtension_3
        WHERE c.TravelDate <= DATEADD(month, -13, GETDATE())
    )
```

**Additional information:**

- [Visual Explanation of SQL joins](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)

Comment: Thank you @Markus. The update did fix the syntax error but I am not getting any results? Since I have provided my DataExtension layout and desired output, could you please advise on the usage of query?

Comment: Do you want all entries not in data extension 3 or all matches that have a traveldate at least 13 months ago? Your query fails as I guess there are no null values allowed and present in `c.Cust--ID`. Additionally an inner join does only give results that are present in both joined tables.

Comment: I want ALL records from DataExtension_1 that exists in DataExtension_2 with CustType = 'Student' and Status = 'TRUE' but who do not exists in DataExtension_3 with TravelDate as 13 months or less. I guess, when I am stating NULL condition then it is returning 0 since I can either go with NULL or TravelDate, correct? Can you please show me an example of how I will get all entried not in data extension 3 VS all matches travel date at least 13? Just so that I can understand.

Comment: If I now understood correctly you just want to filter using the third data extension. If that is the case, try the query in my updated answer.

Comment: you're missing a right paren in the where clause

Comment: What is the difference between your updated query and this (both giving different results)? `SELECT a.CustID, a.CustEmail, b.CustType, b.Status FROM DataExtension_1 AS a INNER JOIN DataExtension_2 AS b ON a.CustID = b.Cust-ID INNER JOIN DataExtension_3 AS c ON a.CustID = c.Cust--ID WHERE b.CustType = 'Student' AND b.Status='true' AND c.TravelDate < DATEADD(month, -13, GETDATE())` AND if I want any one with Travel date 13months or more..then should I do `c.TravelDate >= DATEADD(month, -13, GETDATE())` ?

Comment: When using `>=` you select all records having a traveldate starting with 13 months ago. The query is different as you are *joining* the data of three tables and more specifically as it is an *inner join* the data contained in all of the three data extensions, please see the link I shared in my answer to see how different join types work. In the query I suggested you are using the data of Data Extension 3 to filter out results of the intersection of data extension 1 and 2 matching the where criteria. Please mark my answer as accepted if it helped! Additionally I suggest reading a SQL tutorial.

Comment: I am sorry but I am a little confused. I know I mentioned in my original request "TravelDate as 13 months or less" but I just realised that I need records for TravelDate as 13 months or more (meaning TravelDate should be at least 13 months old). How it will change the query?

Comment: Check out the query in my answer, however note that marketing cloud automation studio might use another timezone than your stored dates. Moreover you need to use a field of type date or datetime for the comparison operators to work like expected.

Comment: Thanks @MarkusSlabina, I have read the article you provided. It does help but I think I am missing out something where. I would appreciate your help. In the results, I am getting rows with TravelDate from 2017 while records should be from July 16 or earlier only. I am not sure where I am going wrong?

Comment: please update your question to include a screenshot of data extension 3's properties (the field types, etc.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63943/discussion-between-kuml-and-markus-slabina).